# Weird xml c# problem, does Vista cache program files?

Tags: c#, xml

My c# program reads an xml file when it loads, my installer installs the program in %program files%\myapp. When I run my program it loads an old xml file and not the one found in its current folder, here is the weird bit, if I rename the myapp folder to myapp2 and rerun the exe the correct xml file loads. I have made no changes to any of the files within the myapp folder, only the installer knows the actual location of the myapp folder and the installer is very simple. There is no hard coded paths in the code. If I copy the myapp folder to the desktop the correct xml files loads.

What is going on here? Anyone seen something similar? Sorry this is vague I have nothing else to go on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does Vista cache program files?

In short: yes ... see this blog post: [Vista Program Files Hide and Seek](http://www.clipboardextender.com/off-topic/vista-program-files-hide-and-seek)